# Unable to start/stop apache on Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2

I am trying to start apache using the following command:

```
sudo -E -u [my_username] /usr/sbin/apachectl -f conf/httpd.conf
```

I get the following error:

```
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

The only 2 changes I have made to httpd.conf are as below:

```
Listen [IP address]:8081
<VirtualHost [IP address]:8081>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://[IP address]$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I am trying to get apache configured on a remote server so I cannot use localhost

Can anyone guide me as to where I maybe going wrong?

Comment: httpd.conf is not used anymore, so which version of Ubuntu are you using? (an older one, I assume). Is apache or something else already using the port? Use `sudo netstat -plnt` to observe.

Comment: It is listening on 8080 ----> tcp        0      0 69.173.71.171:8080          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -  but I used port 8081 and not 8080

Answer (score 0):

It could be your firewall causing the problem. Try opening port `8081` with `iptables` like this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
```

Or if you're using `UFW`:

```
sudo ufw allow 8081
```

Comment: I don't have sudo on the system, I tried the above 2 but permission denied. But if I understand correctly the above commands are to insert the port number into iptable I am trying to access?

Comment: Yes exactly, the port number you have apache listening on, is the one you have to open with iptables so traffic can pass through the firewall.